# Simple examples of Recursive Enumerable Functions

Tags: turing-machines, computability, recursion

My understanding of Recursively Enumerable Functions is that they're recursive functions, but for some values of the arguments you put into the function they will stop and give an answer, and for others, they will go on forever and they will never ever stop.

What are some easy-to-understand examples of Recursively Enumerable Functions?

Comment: [Recursively enumerable languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language) are recognizable languages. The wording is a bit confusing - so it doesn't literally mean "recursive". The same goes with functions.

Comment: Any written computer function is recursively enumerable.